# sencha touch prompt issue

Tags: dialog, sencha-touch, prompt

I try to create a prompt dialog in the following manner:

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('Add item',
   'Add an item to this list:',
    function(btn, text){
      if(btn == 'ok'){
        //do stuff...
      }
    },
    null, false, 'foo', null);
```

Unfortunately this gives me an empty prompt box (no possibility of entering text, and the default value `'foo'` does not appear in the text field).

What am I doing wrong? (tested on chromium and an android 2.1 phone).

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably Sencha bug

Instead of promptConfig set to null, try to set **maxlength** property in it

Example:

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('Add item', 
'Add an item to this list:',
    function(btn, text){
         if(btn == 'ok'){
             //do stuff...
         }
    },
this, false, 'foo', {maxlength: 100});
```

Works in Chrome 15

Comment: I tried your fix on chrome 12 without luck. Might be a chrome/sencha problem... Anyway, without a solution that works on most deployed phones, sencha touch is not that useful. What is *really* bugging me is that the kitchen sink example in the toolkit appears to work!

Comment: So maybe try to set {mexlength: undefined} - also works on chrome 15 and Android Gingerbread browser and is much more elegant than setting strict value :) And kitchen sink example doesn't work for me

Comment: Nah, still no cookie :( Invoking `prompt` *can* be done from a controller, right?